# Quarkus Nullpointer/IllegalArgument exception on Shutdown

Tags: java, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that crawls websites. Usually 2000 pods run (in kubernetes) with the application. When I release a new version, Kubernetes shuts the pod down. Of the 2000 instances, around 75 will throw one of the exceptions below. As you can see from the various exceptions, the problem is not clearly identifiable, but my theory (see below could be correct. Do you guys agree with my theory? If so, do you know a possible fix? I already have a custom ShutdownHandler.

What I think that happens:

1. The crawler is busy crawling websites
2. It receives a shutdown signal (SIGTERM and after 30s SIGKILL if it did not stop already)
3. Quarkus starts breaking down and throwing objects away
4. While quarkus is breaking down, the crawler is still running and tries to access an object that is already thrown away.
5. The exception occurs.

```
Exception: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Caused by: null
stackTraceLocalMessage: null
stackTrace: io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.unwrap(ArcContainerImpl.java:808)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.instance(ArcContainerImpl.java:843)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.Instances.resolveBeans(Instances.java:35)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.Instances.resolveBeans(Instances.java:31)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.resolve(InstanceImpl.java:235)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.<init>(InstanceImpl.java:79)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.<init>(InstanceImpl.java:61)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceProvider.get(InstanceProvider.java:39)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceProvider.get(InstanceProvider.java:16)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.RequestProcessorService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.RequestProcessorService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:111)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:18)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.RequestProcessorService_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.RequestProcessorService_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.ProcessorService.process(ProcessorService.java:35)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.ProcessorService_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.crawler.Crawler.createPageOfLastRequestInChain(Crawler.java:109)
com.abc.crwl.crawler.Crawler.processRequestResponse(Crawler.java:72)
com.abc.crwl.crawler.Crawler.processRequestResponse(Crawler.java:65)
com.abc.crwl.crawler.Crawler_ClientProxy.processRequestResponse(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.getAnalyzeRootResultOfValidResponse(RootUrlProcessor.java:190)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.analyzeRoot(RootUrlProcessor.java:156)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.crawl(RootUrlProcessor.java:88)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.process(RootUrlProcessor.java:64)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.process(RootUrlProcessor.java:21)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.runProcessor(AbstractProcessorService.java:91)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.process(AbstractProcessorService.java:43)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.process(AbstractProcessorService.java:33)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.lambda$processDependentProcessors$2(AbstractProcessorService.java:68)
java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.processDependentProcessors(AbstractProcessorService.java:63)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.lambda$process$1(AbstractProcessorService.java:54)
java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1337)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.process(AbstractProcessorService.java:51)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.WebsitePreProcessorService_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.ProcessorService.preProcess(ProcessorService.java:31)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.ProcessorService_ClientProxy.preProcess(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.crwl.preProcessWebsite(crwl.java:72)
com.abc.crwl.crwl.run(crwl.java:50)
com.abc.crwl.crwl_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Main.scan(Main.java:121)
com.abc.crwl.Main.runProductionMode(Main.java:71)
com.abc.crwl.Main.run(Main.java:52)
com.abc.crwl.Main_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:124)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:60)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:31)
```

or this one:

```
Exception: class java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: null
stackTraceLocalMessage: null
stackTrace: com.abc.crwl.domain.model.CrawlContext.addDownloadable(CrawlContext.java:59)
com.abc.crwl.domain.model.CrawlContext_ClientProxy.addDownloadable(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.finishRootPage(RootUrlProcessor.java:73)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.process(RootUrlProcessor.java:66)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor.process(RootUrlProcessor.java:21)
com.abc.crwl.processor.scanrequest.RootUrlProcessor_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.runProcessor(AbstractProcessorService.java:91)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.process(AbstractProcessorService.java:43)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.process(AbstractProcessorService.java:33)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.lambda$processDependentProcessors$2(AbstractProcessorService.java:68)
java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.processDependentProcessors(AbstractProcessorService.java:63)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.lambda$process$1(AbstractProcessorService.java:54)
java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1337)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.AbstractProcessorService.process(AbstractProcessorService.java:51)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.WebsitePreProcessorService_ClientProxy.process(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.ProcessorService.preProcess(ProcessorService.java:31)
com.abc.crwl.service.processor.ProcessorService_ClientProxy.preProcess(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl.preProcessWebsite(Crawl.java:72)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:50)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Main.scan(Main.java:121)
com.abc.crwl.Main.runProductionMode(Main.java:71)
com.abc.crwl.Main.run(Main.java:52)
com.abc.crwl.Main_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:124)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:60)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:31)
```

or this one:

```
Exception: class java.lang.RuntimeException
Caused by: Error injecting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService.objectMapper
stackTraceLocalMessage: Error injecting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService.objectMapper
stackTrace: com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:111)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:18)
com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_ClientProxy.get(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl.preProcessWebsite(Crawl.java:71)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:50)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Main.scan(Main.java:121)
com.abc.crwl.Main.runProductionMode(Main.java:71)
com.abc.crwl.Main.run(Main.java:52)
com.abc.crwl.Main_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:124)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:60)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:31)

Exception: class java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: null
stackTraceLocalMessage: null
stackTrace: com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:111)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:35)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:32)
io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:18)
com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.service.ProxyService_ClientProxy.get(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl.preProcessWebsite(Crawl.java:71)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:50)
com.abc.crwl.Crawl_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
com.abc.crwl.Main.scan(Main.java:121)
com.abc.crwl.Main.runProductionMode(Main.java:71)
com.abc.crwl.Main.run(Main.java:52)
com.abc.crwl.Main_ClientProxy.run(Unknown Source)
io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:124)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.doRun(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:60)
io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint.main(QuarkusEntryPoint.java:31)
```

Comment: If I were you, I would create a shutdown hook that would stop the crwaling process